# How to implement Google Fit step counter within a Fragment

Tags: android, google-fit

I've been looking for a solution to this and I came across several answers that didn't fit the use-case. The [sample code from Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/tree/master/BasicSensorsApi) works fine if imported as is, but the code sits in an Activity and is messy if you want to integrate into a real project where the code would ideally be in a fragment.

The issue is with the **enableAutoManage** functionality and what to do in the fresh install case where the googleApiClient is built but the authentication/account-pick screen is not yet done and you end up with connection failed on the googleApiClient. I'm going to answer this in full, below.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample **Activity** that will load the GoogleFit_Fragment into the FrameLayout:

```
public class Main_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static int USER_AUTHORISED_REQUEST_CODE = 5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*
            This will load the GoogleFit_Fragment into the FrameLayout, 
            which will cause the buildFitnessClient() function to be called from the Fragment,
            which will cause this Activity to popup the authentication screen
        */

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new GoogleFit_Fragment()).commit();

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        /*
            The result of the account chooser is here,
            send it to the fragment so we can handle it inside
        */

        fragmentReplace.onActivityResult(USER_AUTHORISED_REQUEST_CODE, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

**The GoogleFit_Fragment:**

```
public class GoogleFit_Fragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = "Sample";
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiFitnessClient;
    private OnDataPointListener mListener;

    private View fragmentView;

    private Activity parentActivity;

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (googleApiFitnessClient != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onStop REACHED, client not null and is connected");
            googleApiFitnessClient.stopAutoManage(getActivity());
            googleApiFitnessClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (googleApiFitnessClient != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResume REACHED, client not null");
            googleApiFitnessClient.stopAutoManage(getActivity());
            googleApiFitnessClient.disconnect();
            googleApiFitnessClient.connect();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResume REACHED, client null, buildingClient");
            buildFitnessClient();
            googleApiFitnessClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        if (context instanceof Activity) {
            parentActivity = (Activity) context;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_google_fit, container, false);

        initializeLogging();

        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            requestPermissions();
        }

        return fragmentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == Main_Activity.USER_AUTHORISED_REQUEST_CODE && googleApiFitnessClient != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Activity result finished authorissation, disconnect the client and reconnect");

            googleApiFitnessClient.stopAutoManage(getActivity());
            googleApiFitnessClient.disconnect();
            googleApiFitnessClient.connect();
        }
    }

    private void buildFitnessClient() {
        googleApiFitnessClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(parentActivity)
                .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
//                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
//                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_NUTRITION_READ_WRITE))
//                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE))
                .addConnectionCallbacks(
                        new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
                                // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.
                                findFitnessDataSources();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                                // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
                                // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
                                if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                                } else if (i
                                        == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                    Log.i(TAG,
                                            "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                )
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(
                        new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed! " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
                            }
                        }
                )
                .enableAutoManage((FragmentActivity) parentActivity, 0, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Google Play services connection failed. Cause: " +
                                result.toString());
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    private void findFitnessDataSources() {
        // Note: Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources() requires the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(googleApiFitnessClient, new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
                // At least one datatype must be specified.
                .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
                // Can specify whether data type is raw or derived.
                .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
                .build())
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + dataSourcesResult.getStatus().toString());
                        for (DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Data source found: " + dataSource.toString());
                            Log.i(TAG, "Data Source type: " + dataSource.getDataType().getName());

                            //Let's register a listener to receive Activity data!
                            if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
                                    && mListener == null) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Data source for " + dataSource.getDataType() + " found!  Registering.");
                                registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource,
                                        DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Register a listener with the Sensors API for the provided {@link DataSource} and
     * {@link DataType} combo.
     */
    private void registerFitnessDataListener(DataSource dataSource, DataType dataType) {
        mListener = new OnDataPointListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                for (Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                    Value val = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Detected DataPoint field: " + field.getName());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Detected DataPoint value: " + val);
                }
            }
        };

        Fitness.SensorsApi.add(
                googleApiFitnessClient,
                new SensorRequest.Builder()
                        .setDataSource(dataSource) // Optional but recommended for custom data sets.
                        .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE) // Can't be omitted.
                        .setSamplingRate(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build(),
                mListener)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Listener registered!");
                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Listener not registered.");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void initializeLogging() {
        /*
            Not really needed, you can just log to Logcat without having a view in this fragment
         */
        LogWrapper logWrapper = new LogWrapper();
        Log.setLogNode(logWrapper);
        MessageOnlyLogFilter msgFilter = new MessageOnlyLogFilter();
        logWrapper.setNext(msgFilter);
        LogView logView = (LogView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.sample_logview);

        logView.setTextAppearance(parentActivity, R.style.Log);

        logView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        msgFilter.setNext(logView);
        Log.i(TAG, "Ready");
    }

    /**
     * Return the current state of the permissions needed.
     */
    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(parentActivity,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
        boolean shouldProvideRationale =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(parentActivity,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        if (shouldProvideRationale) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");
            Snackbar.make(
                    fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.main_activity_view),
                    R.string.permission_rationale,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Request permission
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(parentActivity,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS},
                                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(parentActivity,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildFitnessClient();
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(
                        fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.main_activity_view),
                        R.string.permission_denied_explanation,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .setAction(R.string.settings, new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(
                                        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Flow:**

1. Launch app
2. Google API client is built, causing a connection failed callback, but also causing the Account Picker dialog to appear
3. Account is picked, onActivityResult from Activity is called, result is sent to onActivityResult in Fragment
4. Google API client is restarted (stopAutoManage, disconnect, connect)
5. Logging starts STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE or any other data type you choose

This works and is tested a lot, please ask if you're unsure of anything